# Odoo v15 - Print a report with an Automated Action

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I am trying to use an automated action and a python expression to print a report which features a package's barcode when that package is initially created. I have my report setup with the barcode and other information I need. I have tried several ways to get this to work including:

- Using report_action() to print the report
- Using action = { ... } to print the report

I have not been able to find information on printing with an automated action and odoo studio and would appreciate any assistance, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need automated printing then you most likely need third party addon.
Someting like thet:
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/15.0/printnode_base/

If you want to just open the pdf then you can create report action and then print it from the browser.

Comment: How would you go about creating a report action. I have tried doing something like 

env.ref('stock.action_report_quant_package_barcode_small').report_action(record) 

and it doesn't give me any error but it also doesn't download the report. I have also tried
 
action = {
    'type': 'ir.actions.report',
    'name': 'Package Barcode with Content copy(1)',
    'model': 'stock.quant.package',
    'report_type': 'qweb-pdf',
    'report_name': 'stock.action_report_quant_package_barcode_small',
  }

but I run into the same issues where no errors are thrown, but nothing happens